# Why does returning a &[u8] rather than u8 from a function in Rust borrow self?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

I have the following code

```
pub struct Something {
    value: usize,
}

impl Something {
    pub fn get_and_increment(&mut self) -> &[u8] {
        let res = self.get();
        self.value += 1;

        res
    }

    pub fn get(&self) -> &[u8] {
        &[3; 2]
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this I get this error:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `self.value` because it is borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:8:9
  |
7 |         let res = self.get();
  |                   ---- borrow of `self.value` occurs here
8 |         self.value += 1;
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `self.value` occurs here
```

If I change the return type of each function to `u8` rather than `&[u8]` it compiles just fine:

```
pub struct Something {
    value: usize,
}

impl Something {
    pub fn get_and_increment(&mut self) -> u8 {
        let res = self.get();
        self.value += 1;

        res
    }

    pub fn get(&self) -> u8 {
        3
    }
}
```

Why is it that Rust doesn't let me use the `value` property of `Something` in the `get_and_increment` function after `self.get` is called but only when both functions return `&[u8]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend going back and re-reading [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/), specifically the chapter about [references and borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html).

> Why does returning a &[u8] rather than u8 from a function in Rust borrow self?

You are *essentially* asking

> why does returning «something that is borrowed» rather than «something that is not borrowed» from a function «require a borrow»?

The contrite answer is: because a `u8` is not borrowed while a `&[u8]` is borrowed.

> Why is it that Rust doesn't let me use the `value` property

Because the compiler doesn't know what values of `self` are returned as part of `get` when checking the body of `get_and_increment`. It's entirely possible that your implementation of `get` returns a reference to `value`, *or it might in the future*, so the compiler has to take the conservative route and disallow it.

> but only when both functions return `&[u8]`?

This is not accurate. The return type of `get_and_increment` has no impact on the error. The return type of `get` only matters in that it contains a reference.

---

There's no obvious reason for you to return a reference, however:

```
pub fn get(&self) -> [u8; 2] {
    [3; 2]
}
```

If you wanted to return a reference for some reason, it doesn't need to be tied to the lifetime of `self` (which your code does due to [*lifetime elision*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision)):

```
pub fn get(&self) -> &'static [u8] {
    &[3; 2]
}
```

See also:

- [Why can I return a reference to a local literal but not a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50345139/155423)