# Why is it possible to return a mutable reference to a literal from a function?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

The current edition of [*The Rustonomicon*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.39.0/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html) has this example code:

```rust
use std::mem;

pub struct IterMut<'a, T: 'a>(&'a mut [T]);

impl<'a, T> Iterator for IterMut<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a mut T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let slice = mem::replace(&mut self.0, &mut []);
        if slice.is_empty() {
            return None;
        }

        let (l, r) = slice.split_at_mut(1);
        self.0 = r;
        l.get_mut(0)
    }
}
```

I'm confused about this line in particular:

```rust
let slice = mem::replace(&mut self.0, &mut []);
//                                    ^^^^^^^
```

How does this borrow check? If this were an immutable borrow, [RFC 1414](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1414-rvalue_static_promotion.md) indicates that the `[]` rvalue should have `'static` lifetime, so that an immutable borrow would borrow-check, but the example shows a mutable borrow! It seems that one of two things must be going on:

- Either `[]` is a temporary (so that it can be used mutably), in which case it would not have `'static` lifetime, and should not borrow-check;
- Or that `[]` has `'static` lifetime, and therefore it should not be possible to take a mutable borrow (since we don't guarantee exclusive access as we take the borrow), and should not borrow-check.

What am I missing?

Related:

- [Why can I return a reference to a local literal but not a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50345139/155423)

  This question focuses on immutable references; this question is about **mutable** references.
- [Why is it legal to borrow a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47662253/155423)

  This question focuses on taking references inside of a function; this question is about **returning** a reference.

Comment: OK, so `[]` is a literal, and therefore statically allocated, I guessed that might be part of it. But then why are we able to take a mutable reference to the common structure? Mutable references are supposed to be exclusive...

Comment: The other part of the answer appears to be that zero-sized types allow mutable references. Quoting [rfc1414](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1414-rvalue_static_promotion.md): "...aliasing mutable references are only safe for zero sized types (since you never dereference the pointer for them)."

Comment: @Shepmaster I think this is a different question than the original, and I've re-written to make that more clear. I'm not sure that my comments above accurately reflect the current state (the text I quoted from rfc1414 suggests that the handling of zero-sized types could be improved in an extension to that RFC), so this may deserve a more authoritative response.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TL;DR: empty arrays are special cased in the compiler and it's safe because you can't ever dereference the pointer of a zero-length array, so there's no possible mutable aliasing.

---

[RFC 1414](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1414-rvalue_static_promotion.html), rvalue static promotion, discusses the mechanism by which values are promoted to `static` values. It has a section about possible extensions for [mutable references](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1414-rvalue_static_promotion.html#alternatives-extensions) (bolding mine):

> It would be possible to extend support to `&'static mut` references,
>   as long as there is the additional constraint that the
>   referenced type is zero sized.
>
> This again **has precedence in the array reference constructor**:
>
> ```rust
> // valid code today
> let y: &'static mut [u8] = &mut [];
> ```
>
> The rules would be similar:
>
> - If a mutable reference to a constexpr rvalue is taken. (`&mut <constexpr>`)
> - And the constexpr does not contain a `UnsafeCell { ... }` constructor.
> - And the constexpr does not contain a const fn call returning a type containing a `UnsafeCell`.
> - *And the type of the rvalue is zero-sized.*
> - Then instead of translating the value into a stack slot, translate
>     it into a static memory location and give the resulting reference a
>     `'static` lifetime.
>
> **The zero-sized restriction is there because
>   aliasing mutable references are only safe for zero sized types
>   (since you never dereference the pointer for them)**.

From this, we can tell that mutable references to empty arrays are currently special-cased in the compiler. In Rust 1.39, the discussed extension has *not* been implemented:

```
struct Zero;

fn example() -> &'static mut Zero {
    &mut Zero
}
```

```
error[E0515]: cannot return reference to temporary value
 --> src/lib.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     &mut Zero
  |     ^^^^^----
  |     |    |
  |     |    temporary value created here
  |     returns a reference to data owned by the current function
```

While the array version does work:

```
fn example() -> &'static mut [i32] {
    &mut []
}
```

See also:

- [Why is it legal to borrow a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47662253/155423)
- [Why can I return a reference to a local literal but not a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50345139/155423)