# Can I reassign a mutable slice reference to a sub-slice of itself?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrowing

I'm implementing a stack-like structure, where the structure holds a mutable reference to a slice.

```
struct StackLike<'a, X> {
    data: &'a mut [X],
}
```

I'd like to be able to pop the last element off this stack, something like:

```
impl<'a, X> StackLike<'a, X> {
    pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<&'a X> {
        if self.data.is_empty() {
            return None;
        }
        let n = self.data.len();
        let result = &self.data[n - 1];
        self.data = &mut self.data[0..n - 1];
        Some(result)
    }
}
```

This fails:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:11:23
   |
11 |         let result = &self.data[n - 1];
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 6:5...
  --> src/lib.rs:6:5
   |
6  | /     pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<&'a X> {
7  | |         if self.data.is_empty() {
8  | |             return None;
9  | |         }
...  |
13 | |         Some(result)
14 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:11:23
   |
11 |         let result = &self.data[n - 1];
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 5:6...
  --> src/lib.rs:5:6
   |
5  | impl<'a, X> StackLike<'a, X> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/lib.rs:13:9
   |
13 |         Some(result)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected  `std::option::Option<&'a X>`
              found  `std::option::Option<&X>`
```

Even [a simplified version of `pop`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1b403b81ac43f874772bb41e9b990a9d) that doesn't return a value and only shrinks the slice doesn't work.

```
impl<'a, X> StackLike<'a, X> {
    pub fn pop_no_return(&mut self) {
        if self.data.is_empty() {
            return;
        }
        let n = self.data.len();
        self.data = &mut self.data[0..n - 1];
    }
}
```

which gives

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:11:26
   |
11 |         self.data = &mut self.data[0..n - 1];
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 6:5...
  --> src/lib.rs:6:5
   |
6  | /     pub fn pop_no_return(&mut self) {
7  | |         if self.data.is_empty() {
8  | |             return;
9  | |         }
10 | |         let n = self.data.len();
11 | |         self.data = &mut self.data[0..n - 1];
12 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:11:26
   |
11 |         self.data = &mut self.data[0..n - 1];
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 5:6...
  --> src/lib.rs:5:6
   |
5  | impl<'a, X> StackLike<'a, X> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:11:21
   |
11 |         self.data = &mut self.data[0..n - 1];
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Is there a way to make this work, or do I need to track the bounds of the slice I'm interested in more explicitly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I modified Masklinn's code slightly to allow multiple `.pop()`s to be called on the same stack:

```rust
struct StackLike<'a, X> {
    data: &'a mut [X],
}

impl<'a, X> StackLike<'a, X> {
    pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<&'a mut X> {
        let data = std::mem::replace(&mut self.data, &mut []);
        if let Some((last, subslice)) = data.split_last_mut() {
            self.data = subslice;
            Some(last)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let mut stack = StackLike { data: &mut data };

    let x = stack.pop().unwrap();
    let y = stack.pop().unwrap();
    println!("X: {}, Y: {}", x, y);
}
```

The tricky part here is this line (I added a type annotation for explicitness):

```rust
let data: &'a mut [X] = std::mem::replace(&mut self.data, &mut []);
```

We replace `self.data` with an empty slice temporarily so that we can split the slice. If you were to write simply

```rust
let data: &'a mut [X] = self.data;
```

the compiler would be unhappy:

```
error[E0312]: lifetime of reference outlives lifetime of borrowed content...
  --> src/main.rs:7:33
   |
7  |         let data: &'a mut [X] = self.data;
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: ...the reference is valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 5:6...
  --> src/main.rs:5:6
   |
5  | impl<'a,  X> StackLike<'a, X> {
   |      ^^
note: ...but the borrowed content is only valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 6:5
  --> src/main.rs:6:5
   |
6  | /     pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<&'a mut X> {
7  | |         let data: &'a mut [X] = self.data;
8  | |         if let Some((last, subslice)) = data.split_last_mut() {
9  | |             self.data = subslice;
...  |
13 | |         }
14 | |     }
   | |_____^
```

As far as I understand it, the problem is that `self.data` is a mutable reference, and mutable references are not `Copy` (remember, you can only have one at a time). And you cannot move out of `self.data` since `self` is a mutable reference, not an owner. So what the compiler tries to do is to reborrow `self.data`, which "infects" it with with the lifetime of `&mut self`. This is a dead end: we want the reference to live for `'a`, but it is actually valid only for the lifetime of `&mut self`, and these lifetimes are generally unrelated (and they don't need to be related), which leaves the compiler perplexed.

To aid the compiler, we use `std::mem::replace` to explicitly move the slice out of `self.data` and temporarily replace it with an empty slice, [which can be any lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56066534/3650362). Now we can do anything with `data` without tangling it with the lifetime of `&mut self`.

Comment: Brilliant. Exactly what I was going to suggest. It may be worth noting that the "temporary" replacement of the slice ends up being permanent if `self.data` starts out empty (because you lose the original slice when `split_last_mut` returns `None`). Practically, this probably isn't an issue, because all empty slices are more or less equivalent, but it could lead to surprises if you were doing something tricky with the address of the data.

Comment: Return type of `pop` doesn't need to hold a mutable reference, i.e.: `pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<&'a X>`.

Comment: Indeed, I added it myself, because otherwise `data` could as well be `&'a [X]` and the question becomes somewhat easier.

Answer (score 0):

For sub-question 2, you need to indicate the relation between `&mut self` and `'a` otherwise they're considered unrelated. I don't know if there's a shortcut via lifetime elision but if you specify that `self` lives for `'a` you're fine.

For sub-question 1, the compiler doesn't "see through" function calls (including indexing which desugars to a function call), so it does not know that `&self.data[n - 1]` and `&mut self.data[0..n-1]` are non-overlapping. You need to use [`split_mut_last`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_last_mut).

```
struct StackLike<'a, X> {
    data: &'a mut [X],
}

impl<'a, X> StackLike<'a, X> {
    pub fn pop(&'a mut self) -> Option<&'a X> {
        if let Some((last, subslice)) = self.data.split_last_mut() {
            self.data = subslice;
            Some(last)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3b2f7689efc4c6cdb6ac0387c2e51b4d)

Comment: One pretty major downside with this is because `pop` must take `&'a mut self`, it seems like you won't be able to call `.pop()` twice because it needs a mutable reference with the entire lifetime of the stack. [Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e10de33c6291e4f4771211acc64b9d00)