# What does adding an int to a uint8_t pointer really do?

Tags: c, pointers, rust

I don't code in C much, but I am currently (attempting) to port a C project to Rust, and I don't understand what this does:

```
void example(const uint8_t *m, unsigned int r)
{
    m += r;
}
```

After a bit of Googling, I ***think*** that it's the same as `m = m[r]`. But if that is true, `m` and `m[r]` are two different data types (right...?). Trying to replicate this in Rust:

```
fn example(m: &mut [u8], r: u32) {
    m = m[r];
}
```

This gives the error `` mismatched types: expected `&mut [u8]`, found `u8 ``, which makes sense. I either did the Rust part wrong, or I did not fully understand what the C part does. Can someone please explain where I went wrong?

Comment: It is the same as `m = &m[r]` (note the `&`).

Comment: @Jmb But then you would be assigning **uint8_t to *uint8_t! How does that work?

Comment: No you wouldn't. `m[r]` is of type `uint8_t`. So `&m[r]` is of type `uint8_t *`

Comment: Rust is much strongly typed than C, and on a type level, Rust's slices don't really compare to C's pointers so this question doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Can't write an answer just now, but for your Rust code try `m = &mut m[r..]`. Also read [Can I reassign a mutable slice reference to a sub-slice of itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61223234/3650362) if that doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: @trentcl That might seem to work. I can’t test it rn but I get the idea.

Comment: code do nothing.

Comment: The C code is just a very verbose no-op. It is passed a pointer and an integer value, performs an addition, and then doesn't do anything with the result. The effect of calling `example` is the same as not calling `example`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a pointer `m` to some element in an array, say `x`, and an integer `r`, `m += r` adjusts `m` to point to the element that is `r` elements after `x`.

For example, if `m` points to `a[3]` and `r` is 5, then `m += r` changes `m` to point to `a[8]`.

In the case where `m` is a `uint8_t *`, it must point to elements that are bytes, and advancing `m` by `r` elements advances the pointer by `r` bytes. In cases where `m` points to a larger type, such as when `m` is `int *`, advancing `m` by `r` elements advances the pointer by `r*s` bytes, where `s` is the number of bytes in each element.

In many C implementations, bytes in memory are simply numbered consecutively starting with 0 (although not all bytes may be mapped in a virtual address space), and a pointer is represented with the number of the byte it points to. In this case, to increment a pointer by n bytes, the C implementation simply adds n to its representation. In C implementations with more complicated memory models, the C implementation performs whatever manipulations are needed to produce a pointer to the proper place.