How to write_all to a slice in Rust many times and get output
use std::io::Write;

pub struct A{
    pub a: u8,
    pub b: u16
}

impl A {
    pub fn to_bytes(&self, output: &mut &mut[u8]) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
        output.write_all(&[self.a])?;
        output.write_all(&self.b.to_be_bytes()[..])?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut buffer: &mut [u8] = &mut [0u8; 10];
    let a = A{
        a: 7,
        b: 100
    };
    a.to_bytes(&mut buffer);
    println!("{:?}", buffer);
}

this prints [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] because it splits the slice and gives the rest for more writes. playground
What would be the most elegant way to get the actual output after many writes, and not the remainder slice? I don't want to keep track of how many bytes were written just so I can subslice the buffer output.
Context: microcontrollers don't allow for memory allocation so I pass a worst case buffer slice for write and it's almost never filled to the end.

Mutate a reborrow so that buffer keeps the original range:
impl A {
    pub fn to_bytes(&self, mut output: &mut[u8]) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
        ...             // ^^^
    }
}

fn main() {
    ...
    a.to_bytes(buffer);
    ...
}

It will print:
[7, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

playground link

If you want to write the data, keep track of how many bytes were written, and use that to affect buffer in-place; you can accomplish that like so:
impl A {
    pub fn to_bytes(&self, buffer: &mut &mut[u8]) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
        let mut output = &mut **buffer;
        
        let space = output.len();
        
        output.write_all(&[self.a])?;
        output.write_all(&self.b.to_be_bytes()[..])?;
        
        let written = space - output.len();
        
        // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61223234/can-i-reassign-a-mutable-slice-reference-to-a-sub-slice-of-itself
        // for in-place mutable sub-slicing
        let orig = std::mem::replace(buffer, &mut []);
        *buffer = &mut orig[..written];
        
        Ok(())
    }
}

with your code will print:
[7, 0, 100]

playground link
It would likely be more extensible and ergonomic if you just returned the bytes written and slice yourself, but to each their own.

yes but the problem is that it prints everything, while I want to print just how much was written. I could return the length on the to_bytes and subslice the output, but is there an automatic way so the output is already subsliced to the correct length?

Option 1: Use std::io::Cursor. A cursor has a "current position" for reads/writes. The position after the writes tells us how many bytes were written.
use std::io::{self, Cursor, Write};

pub struct A {
    pub a: u8,
    pub b: u16,
}

impl A {
    pub fn to_bytes(&self, output: &mut Cursor<&mut [u8]>) -> io::Result<()> {
        output.write_all(&[self.a])?;
        output.write_all(&self.b.to_be_bytes()[..])?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut buffer: &mut [u8] = &mut [0u8; 10];
    let mut cursor = Cursor::new(buffer);
    let a = A { a: 7, b: 100 };
    a.to_bytes(&mut cursor);
    println!("{:?}", &cursor.get_ref()[..cursor.position() as usize]);
}

Option 2: Make a copy (or more precisely, a reborrow) of the whole slice in another variable and pass that to to_bytes, then calculate the difference in length between the two slices to get how many bytes were written.
use std::io::{self, Write};

pub struct A {
    pub a: u8,
    pub b: u16,
}

impl A {
    pub fn to_bytes(&self, output: &mut &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<()> {
        output.write_all(&[self.a])?;
        output.write_all(&self.b.to_be_bytes()[..])?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut buffer: &mut [u8] = &mut [0u8; 10];
    let mut buffer2: &mut [u8] = &mut buffer;
    let a = A { a: 7, b: 100 };
    a.to_bytes(&mut buffer2);
    // `buffer2.len()` needs to be evaluated in a separate statement...
    let remaining_len = buffer2.len();
    // ...so that `buffer2`'s lease can end,
    // which lets us use `buffer` again.
    println!("{:?}", &buffer[..(buffer.len() - remaining_len)]);
}

In both cases, the output is [7, 0, 100].


Is there a way to do the reborrow inside the ˋto_bytesˋ implementation so it's less error prone?

Yes, we can move that logic inside to_bytes and have to_bytes return the slice that contains the written data.
use std::io::{self, Write};

pub struct A {
    pub a: u8,
    pub b: u16,
}

impl A {
    pub fn to_bytes<'a>(&self, output: &'a mut [u8]) -> io::Result<&'a mut [u8]> {
        let mut output_tail: &mut [u8] = &mut *output;
        output_tail.write_all(&[self.a])?;
        output_tail.write_all(&self.b.to_be_bytes()[..])?;
        let remaining_len = output_tail.len();
        let total_len = output.len();
        Ok(&mut output[..(total_len - remaining_len)])
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut buffer: &mut [u8] = &mut [0u8; 10];
    let a = A { a: 7, b: 100 };
    println!("{:?}", a.to_bytes(&mut buffer));
}


is there a way to do the reborrow inside the ˋto_bytesˋ implementation so it's less error prone? When done many times for each call, something can be done wrong

@GuerlandoOCs I edited my answer to add another example.
