# Why returning a reference owned by the current function is allowed in Rust?

Tags: struct, rust, initialization, lifetime, ownership

I am learning Rust's lifetime/ownership concepts, and would like to explain the following behavior in Rust (rustc 1.37.0).

For a program like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Book {
    price: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let book1 = Book {price: 12};
    let cheaper_book = choose_cheaper(&book1);
    println!("{:?}", cheaper_book);
}

fn choose_cheaper(b1: &Book) -> &Book {
    if b1.price < 15 {
        b1
    } else {
        let cheapest_book = Book {price: 0};
        &cheapest_book
    }
}
```

Rust reports:

```
17 |   &cheapest_book
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a reference to data owned by the current function
```

And I can understand this error and it is because variable `cheapest_book` is the owner of the Book with price 0, and it will be dropped at the end of this function, so the returned reference will become invalid after that. But it is hard for me to explain why the following is allowed if I change the `choose_cheaper` function to be:

```rust
fn choose_cheaper(b1: &Book) -> &Book {
    if b1.price < 15 {
        b1
    } else {
        let cheapest_book = &Book {price: 0};
        cheapest_book
    }
}
```

Could some one shed me some light on it? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I return a reference to a local literal but not a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345139/why-can-i-return-a-reference-to-a-local-literal-but-not-a-variable)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the line `let cheapest_book = &Book {price: 0};`, the `Book` is *not* a "new" instance of the `Book` type. Every time this function is called it will return a reference to the *same* instance of the `Book` type, which will be stored in the read-only data section of the executable (or, technically, the data section if it contains a `Cell` or `AtomicUsize` or the like).

We can in this instance "expand" the code into something a little more explicit:

```rust
static GLOBAL_BOOK: Book = Book { price: 0 };

fn choose_cheaper<'a>(b1: &'a Book) -> &'a Book {
    if b1.price < 15 {
        b1
    } else {
        let cheapest_book = &GLOBAL_BOOK;
        cheapest_book
    }
}
```

Note that the reference to `GLOBAL_BOOK` could actually be a `&'static Book`, but `&'a Book` is a supertype of that so it's okay to return the static reference as if it were an `'a` reference.

If this seems weird, consider that this is exactly what happens with string literals; they just don't have the explicit `&` character: After `let foo = "string!";`, `foo` is a `&'static str` referencing some data in the read-only section of the executable, not a local object. So you can also write `return "string!";` in functions returning `&'a str` for any `'a`.

The rule for whether rust will make this transformation is whenever you "construct" an object (using tuple syntax, or struct or enum or union initialization syntax, or numeric or string literals, or any combinations thereof - **not** function calls to `new()` or any other function) behind a `&`, they'll become an anonymous static. So in fact `&&1_u32` is a `'static` reference to a static `'static` reference to a static `u32`.

Comment: Worth mentioning: the term for this behavior is "static promotion" https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38865