# Why does Rust reuse memory with same value

Tags: memory, rust, borrow

Example code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut y = &5; // 1

    println!("{:p}", y);

    {
        let x = &2; // 2
        println!("{:p}", x);
        y = x;
    }

    y = &3; // 3
    println!("{:p}", y);
}
```

If third assignment contains `&3` then code output:

```
0x558e7da926a0
0x558e7da926a4
0x558e7da926a8
```

If third assignment contains `&2` (same value with second assignment) then code output:

```
0x558e7da926a0
0x558e7da926a4
0x558e7da926a4
```

If third assignment contains `&5` (same value with first assignment) then code output:

```
0x558e7da926a0
0x558e7da926a4
0x558e7da926a0
```

Why does rust not free memory but reuse it if the assignment value is the same or allocate a new block of memory otherwise?

Comment: Why do you want it to allocate more memory when the same memory can be safely re-used?

Comment: @Thilo, I think so but why does Rust do that? I think Rust can free memory after second and third assignments.

Comment: There is no benefit in free a variable on the stack and then reallocate it with the same value a few instructions later, if there is nothing more important to store there. Works as it should.

Comment: If these things are allocated from the stack, it would be very wasteful to allocate and free them one by one. Usually, the whole stackframe gets added/removed in one go when functions enter/return. If they are "allocated" as static constants, they don't need dynamic memory management at all.

Comment: @Simson, Thanks I understood.

Comment: rule number one of system language, don't assume ~memory~ anything.

Comment: I've heard of half assing, but this is the first I'm learning about third assing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I return a reference to a local literal but not a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345139/why-can-i-return-a-reference-to-a-local-literal-but-not-a-variable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two occurrences of the same literal number are indistinguishable. You cannot expect the address of two literals to be identical, and neither can you expect them to be different.

This allows the compiler (but in fact it is free to do otherwise) to emit one `5` data in the executable code, and have all `&5` refer to it. Constants *may* (see comment) also have a static lifetime, in which case they are not allocated/deallocated during program execution, they always are allocated.

Comment: Constants *may* be promoted to statics, but in general they may also become temporaries or be compiled away entirely. 5 gets the static promotion treatment here because the code explicitly takes its address; if that weren't so, the compiler would be free to create it in a register or optimize it out of existence, with no 5 appearing in the binary at all.

Comment: @trentcl I think that it is guaranteed, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345139/why-can-i-return-a-reference-to-a-local-literal-but-not-a-variable

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios It's guaranteed *because* the address is taken, but constants in general are not subject to static promotion. My earlier comment was to clarify an earlier phrasing of the answer which might have been construed to mean that *all* constants are promoted to statics, which is not true.

Comment: @trentcl: Actually, I would not be surprised to learn it is NOT guaranteed. Specifically, if the compiler was able to *elide* the address, for example in code such as `let x = &5; println!("{}", 1 + *x);` then I would not expect to find a literal `5` in the data section of the binary, I'd expect to see a `6` directly embedded in the assembly.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of tricks an optimizing compiler can use to determine if a variable can be assigned a constant value. Your findings are consistent with this, no need to run duplicate code if it is not needed.