# Temporary value dropped while borrowed, but I don't want to do a let

Tags: rust, borrowing

I'm doing something like this:

```
fn main() {
    //[1, 0, 0, 0, 99]; // return [2, 0, 0, 0, 99]
    //[2, 3, 0, 3, 99]; // return [2,3,0,6,99]
    //[2, 4, 4, 5, 99, 0]; // return [2,4,4,5,99,9801]
    //[1, 1, 1, 4, 99, 5, 6, 0, 99]; // return [30,1,1,4,2,5,6,0,99]

    let map: Vec<(&mut [usize], &[usize])> = vec![(&mut [1, 0, 0, 0, 99], &[2, 0, 0, 0, 99])];

    for (x, y) in map {
        execute_program(x);
        assert_eq!(x, y);
    }
}

pub fn execute_program(vec: &mut [usize]) {
    //do something inside vec
}
```

[Here the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=59c5a73ce5b901aa37bf4511016ed107)

The problem is that I don't use the let on the first element in the tuple, that i want to borrow to execute_program:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:2:57
  |
2 |     let map: Vec<(&mut [usize], &[usize])> = vec![(&mut [1, 0, 0, 0, 99], &[2, 0, 0, 0, 99])];
  |                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                     - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |                                                         |
  |                                                         creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
3 | 
4 |     for (x, y) in map {
  |                   --- borrow later used here
  |
  = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

But what I was doing was a refactoring exactly because I didn't want to do a `let` for every slice I want to test!

Is the `let` really needed?

Comment: Why are you borrowing there instead of later? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9b799659ac3c5833c114c6486f3773e2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, *some*thing has to own each of those arrays, because references can't own things. And the arrays are of different sizes, so the owner has to be a pointer. The most common array-like owning pointer is `Vec`:

```
let map: Vec<(Vec<usize>, &[usize])> = vec![
    (vec![1, 0, 0, 0, 99], &[2, 0, 0, 0, 99]),
    (vec![2, 3, 0, 3, 99], &[2, 3, 0, 6, 99]),
    (vec![2, 4, 4, 5, 99, 0], &[2, 4, 4, 5, 99, 9801]),
    (vec![1, 1, 1, 4, 99, 5, 6, 0, 99], &[30, 1, 1, 4, 2, 5, 6, 0, 99]),
];

for (mut x, y) in map {
    execute_program(&mut x);
    assert_eq!(x, y);
}
```

The arrays are therefore owned by `map` and borrowed when necessary, as loganfsmyth also suggested in the question comments.

You may be concerned about the performance cost of making unnecessary allocations. This is the cost of using a single `let`; since the arrays are not all the same size, if you want them on the stack there really isn't a way around declaring them with different `let`s. However, you could write a macro that removes the boilerplate.

### Wait, why does it work for `y`?

You may wonder why I turned `x` into a vector, but left `y` as it is. The answer is that because `y` is a shared reference, those arrays are subject to [static promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345139/why-can-i-return-a-reference-to-a-local-literal-but-not-a-variable), so that `&[2, 0, 0, 0, 99]` is actually of type `&'static [usize; 5]` which can be coerced to `&'static [usize]`. `&mut` references do not trigger static promotion because it is unsafe to mutate a static value without some kind of synchronization.