# Rust &str conversion to &'static &str

Tags: rust, type-conversion

I am receiving an `&str` from the application's args, but I need this value as `&'static &str`. How can I convert it?

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7ab020528a0d3e26a49b915542f50c8e

```rust
fn fun(var: &'static &str) {}

fn main() {
    let var: &str = "temp";
    fun(var);
}
```

```bash
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:102:9
    |
102 |         matches.value_of("STATIC-FILES").unwrap(),
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected &str, found str
    |
    = note: expected type `&'static &str`
               found type `&str`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

---

#### @more information

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   ├── main.rs
│   └── server.rs
```

```rust
// file: main.rs
extern crate clap;

use clap::{App, Arg};

mod server;

fn main() {
    let app = App::new("My App")
    .arg(
            Arg::with_name("STATIC-FILES")
                .help("Sets absolute path to client's static files")
                .default_value("/var/www/client"),
        )

    let matches = app.get_matches();

    let s = server::start(
        matches.value_of("STATIC-FILES").unwrap(),
    );
```

```
// file: server.rs
use actix_files as fs;
use actix_web::{guard, web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer};

pub fn start(
    static_files_path: &'static &str,
) -> io::Result<()> {

    let sys = actix_rt::System::new("myappsvr");

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        let sfp = move || static_files_path;
        App::new()
            .service(fs::Files::new("/", sfp()).index_file("index.html"))
    })

    (...)

    .start();

    sys.run();
}
```

In `main.rs` I am starting an HTTP server (Actix). The path to the directory with static files has to be passed as an argument.

`App::new().service(fs::Files::new("/", sfp()).index_file("index.html"))` requires `&'static &str` in place of `sfp()`.

Comment: I would expect you can do this the opposite way, but can't really turn a "dynamic" value into something available statically.

Comment: that not possible you need a `&'static &'static str`

Comment: Sounds like this might be an XY problem. Why do you need a `&'static &str`?

Comment: The question code can be fixed by making a small change: `let var = &"temp";` However I assume this will not work for your actual code, which is why we need more information.

Comment: @trentcl I was trying to find some information about that, is it transferring the first borrow's lifetime to the second borrow?(&&str) Which makes sense but i couldn't find any reference about the case.

Comment: @ÖmerErden `"temp"` is a const rvalue, which means it's subject to [static promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345139/why-can-i-return-a-reference-to-a-local-literal-but-not-a-variable). You can take as many `&` references as you want to a literal and as long as you don't coerce them shorter they will all have the `'static` lifetime. [Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ef3170da54b6db03083f5ab6ec84eb84)

Comment: @trentcl looking for this thanks ! And i guess this looks like an answer for this question.

Comment: Definitely looks like an X/Y problem. [`fs::Files::new`](https://docs.rs/actix-files/0.2.0-alpha.3/actix_files/struct.Files.html#method.new) does *not* require its argument to be `'static`; That would be weird.

Comment: Maybe it helps to have `fun` accept a `String`?

Answer (score 4):

When the compiler says you need `&'static`, it doesn't really mean that. It's trying to tell you that **temporary references are not allowed here**.

`&'static str` is a special case that is basically a leaked memory. In 99.99% of cases it's a bad idea to leak memory, so compiler's suggestion is stupid. Don't try to use `&'static str`. Use an owned `String` instead.

Keep in mind that `&str` is not a string by itself, but a read-only view of some string stored elsewhere.

So the real problem is that you've used a temporary `&str`, and you should have used a permanently stored `String` instead.

---

But for the 0.01% of cases where you can leak memory of a string, here's how:

```rust
let leaked: &'static str = Box::leak("hi".to_string().into_boxed_str());
```