# Is there a reason to use &[data] instead of just [data]?

Tags: arrays, pointers, variables, rust, reference

Is there any difference between `arr1` and `arr2`?

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = &[1, 2, 3];
```

I know that the type of `arr1` is `[i32, 3]` and `&[i32, 3]` for `arr2`. I understand this situation:

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
```

and this one:

```
let refer = &arr1;
```

Is there a reason to use `&[data]` instead of just `[data]`?

Comment: Have you read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/)? It talks about why you'd want references vs values, and the same logic is true for arrays.

Comment: I read this book. I understand what references are. I know why to give references to some variable / object. But why give references to the data block "inscribed in the code". I mean for example this: &[1, 2, 3].

Comment: You state *I know why to give references to some variable / object* — **that's why** you can/would take a reference to a literal — because you need a reference. Perhaps your question is answered by [Why is it legal to borrow a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47662253/155423)

Comment: Thank you for link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when using an array (`[i32]`) and assigning it, you are actually creating a new copy of the array. When borrowing you are referencing the original value. In your example you are only using immutable values, so functionally there is not a difference between using arrays and borrowing but if you add mutability you can demonstrate this:

```
let mut array = [1, 2, 3];

let mut copy = array;
copy[0] = 10;

let borrow = &mut array;
borrow[1] = 20;
foo(array);
//print original
println!("array: {:?}", array); //  Prints 'array: [1, 20, 3]'
//print copy
println!("copy: {:?}", copy); // Prints 'copy: [10, 2, 3]'
```

Second, Rust requires that function parameters have a defined size. Because arrays passed by value could be any size, you cannot pass arrays by value without first defining the size of the array in the function definition.

```
fn foo(val: [i32]) { // compile-time error

}
fn bar(val: [i32; 3]) { // allowed

}
```

However, `&[i32]` can be passed to a function because slices have a constant size. This allows you to write functions for arrays of any length rather than one specific size. Furthermore `&[i32]` is a more general type. If you have `[i32]` you can always create a `&[i32]`, but you cannot create a `[i32]` from `&[i32]` without first copying the values.

```
fn foo(val: &[i32]) { // also allowed because &[i32] has a fixed size
   // some stuff
}
```

Comment: @JakubPadło [Why can I return a reference to a local literal but not a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50345139/155423)