# What's the difference between &dyn Trait and Box<dyn Trait> for dynamic dispatch?

Tags: rust, dynamic-dispatch

Functions `new_foo1` and `new_foo2` return the same trait `Foo` using different patterns. I don't see any functional difference between them besides `new_foo1` being more verbose. Is there a preferred way among the two? Is there any subtle ramifications of either pattern?

```rust
trait Foo {
    fn bar(&self);
}

struct FooIm {}

impl Foo for FooIm {
    fn bar(&self) {
        println!("bar from FooIm")
    }
}

fn new_foo1<'a>() -> &'a (dyn Foo + 'a) {
    &FooIm {}
}

fn new_foo2() -> Box<dyn Foo> {
    let f = FooIm {};
    Box::new(f)
}

fn main() {
    let f1 = new_foo1();
    let f2 = new_foo2();

    f1.bar();
    f2.bar();
}
```

Comment: The main difference should come along once you make `new_foo1` a bit more complicated than just returning a literal ([relevant question on the subject of returning references to local values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50345139)). Try for example a `FooIm` that contains heap-allocated data such as a `Vec` or a `String`, and as described in the linked duplicate, only `new_foo2` will compile.

Comment: I see now. But why new_foo1 even exists, if it is so faint?

Comment: @AlekseyKanaev Passing boxes around passes ownership. You often need to pass references around without giving up ownership. This is completely unrelated to trait objects.

Comment: A constructor should always returned an owned object, so in this case returing a reference indeed doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It's a shame that this got closed as a duplicate, because none of the 5 questions mentioned talk specifically about the dyn keyword, barely talk about dynamic dispatch, and some of them are completely irrelevant. If StackOverflow was more concerned with answering questions than closing them as duplicates maybe it wouldn't be losing most of its userbase.

Comment: @SirDorius In my experience some Rust experts (or those who claim to be so) are particularly obnoxious compared to experts in other languages and specialist fields on SO. To answer your particular point about `dyn` though, check out this question both asked and answered by Shepmaster himself: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50650070/595305 . It appears that `dyn` was introduced in version 1.27, so relatively recently (well, that was 6 years ago...).