# I'm new to Rust, can someone help me to understand why the below code can compile?

Tags: rust

Can somebody help me to understand why the code can run ?
How can a method return local temp references out of the scope?

```
fn test_Borrowing3<'a>() -> Vec<&'a i32>
{
        let a: &i32 = &1;
        let b = &2;
        let aa = vec![a, b];
        return aa
}
```

Comment: The answer linked by @Netwave addresses the "reference to constant" thing but returns a `'static` type. This question has the additional `'a` lifetime. The explanation is that a `'static` lifetime lives as long as any other lifetime, so this conversion is allowed (covariance!).

Comment: @rodrigo, for some reason I read can't, too early, need more coffee :D

Comment: @Netwave: Oh, I wasn't criticizing your duplicate, actually I think it was mostly appropriate, I was just commenting this little difference.

Answer (score 1):

As @rodrigo pointed, your lifetime `'a` is a generic lifetime which in this case is converted to a `'static` one, could be similar to:

```rust
fn test_Borrowing3() -> Vec<&'static i32>
{
    let a: &i32 = &1;
    let b = &2;
    let aa = vec![a, b];
    return aa
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c7a1541ee436a09aef73f8e83220d6c1)

For extended explanations see also:

[Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682876/is-there-any-way-to-return-a-reference-to-a-variable-created-in-a-function)

Specifically this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50345206/1695172) from @LukasKalbertodt explains it perfectly.

Comment: It’s more that `'static` is converted to `'a` than the other way around: the caller gets to determine `'a`, and it happens that the actual references being returned are `'static`, which can be converted to `'a`.

Comment: @eggyal, well, the lifetime is promoted to the valid one, in this case 'static. Maybe I didn't express it well, or I do not know how to express it though.