# Understanding Rust Borrowing/Stack Complications

Tags: rust, stack

This rust code doesn't work. Is there any detailed explanation for why?
It gives the error "cannot return reference to temporary value"

```rust
trait NonInherited {
    fn get_type(&self) -> &str;
}

struct Inherited {
    val: usize,
}

impl NonInherited for Inherited {
    fn get_type(&self) -> &str {
        return "inherited";
    }
}

fn helper(list: &mut [usize; 2]) -> &'static dyn NonInherited {

    // works
    //return &Inherited {val: 3};

    // does not work
    return &Inherited {val: list[1]}; // Error is here
}

fn main() {
    let mut a: [usize; 2] = [1, 7];
    println!("{}", helper(&mut a).get_type());
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I return a reference to a local literal but not a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345139/why-can-i-return-a-reference-to-a-local-literal-but-not-a-variable)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that `Inherited { val: 3 }` is a [constant struct expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/constant-items.html) that is evaluated during compilation, however, `Inherited { val: list[1] }` is dynamic which is evaluated during runtime.

As described in Rust reference on [Constant Evaluation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/const_eval.html), constant expressions do not cause any `drop()` to be run, thus, its value is not temporary.

Comment: So the compiler knows how long `3` will be alive. But it can't tell how long `list[1]` will be alive?

Comment: @Basketball Person it's that the 3, being constant data,  allows all of the instances of inherited returned to be folded to a single instance with static lifetime. (Like string literals). References to this instance can be passed around freely, because it will always be there. With a dynamic value like list, each value is a unique object with its own independent lifetime. And that lifetime is the method helper. So references from outside that lifetime are clearly invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the `Inherited` struct is created on the stack in the function `helper`, and then a reference to this stack-resident object is being returned. That's a problem because the lifetime of the `Inherited` struct is only for the scope of the `helper` function.

You can fix this by returning the created struct itself instead of a reference to it. Below is a simple working example, with some of the type names changed for clarity. Notice that the `list` variable does not need to be `mut`.

```rs
trait SomeTrait {
    fn get_type(&self) -> &str;
}

struct SomeStruct {
    val: usize,
}

impl SomeTrait for SomeStruct {
    fn get_type(&self) -> &str {
        return "overridden";
    }
}

fn helper(list: &[usize; 2]) -> impl SomeTrait {

    // works
    return SomeStruct {val: list[1]};
}

fn main() {
    let a: [usize; 2] = [1, 7];
    let b = helper(&a);
    println!("Type is {}", b.get_type());
}
```