# why does rust allow a local struct reference had static lifetime?

Tags: rust

I am reading rusty_v8's source code.

And I found this code:

```
  let vtable: &'static RustAllocatorVtable<AtomicUsize> =
    &RustAllocatorVtable {
      allocate,
      allocate_uninitialized,
      free,
      reallocate,
      drop,
    };
```

https://github.com/denoland/rusty_v8/blob/main/src/array_buffer.rs#L205

I was confused that why `&RustAllocatorVtable{}` had static lifetime. It allocated on stack and will destroyed after the function scope, isn't it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can I return a reference to a local literal but not a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50345139/why-can-i-return-a-reference-to-a-local-literal-but-not-a-variable)

Comment: I knew this is a duplicate, but couldn't find it until I posted my answer! :(

Answer (score 4):

This is called [rvalue static promotion](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1414-rvalue_static_promotion.html) or [constant promotion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html?highlight=prom#constant-promotion). When the compiler faces a value that can be evaluated at compile-time, it promotes it to a `static`, like if you wrote:

```rust
static S: RustAllocatorVtable<AtomicUsize> = RustAllocatorVtable {
    allocate,
    allocate_uninitialized,
    free,
    reallocate,
    drop,
};
let vtable: &'static RustAllocatorVtable<AtomicUsize> = &S;
```

Comment: Thanks. And I wish the rust team explain this point in <the book> more boldly.