# Rust singletons with virtual methods

Tags: rust

How to represent bunch of immutable stateless singletons implementing same traits with dynamic dispatch?

Types/values won't be know at compile time hence the need for virtual methods.

Ideally all values form discriminated union but I already know it's not possible to impl on enum values in Rust.

I.e. equivalent of following Scala code:

```scala
sealed trait Kind {
  def name(): String
}

object A extends Kind {
  def name() = "A"
}

object B extends Kind {
  def name() = "B"
}

def use(x: Kind) = {
  println(s"Kind is ${x.name()}")
}

def main() = {
  use(A)
}
```

For people who don't know Scala - above example allocates only 2 objects and then passes A reference (simple pointer).

I came up with something like this but find it terrible:

```rust
trait Kind {
  fn name(&self) -> String;
}

struct A;
struct B;

impl Kind for A {
  fn name(&self) -> String { String::from("A") }
}

impl Kind for B {
  fn name(&self) -> String { String::form("B") }
}

// not allowed, will have to create new box on every call?
// even lazy_static! does not work
//const A: Box<dyn Kind> = Box::new(A{});

fn use(x: Box<dyn Kind>) {
  println!("Kind is {}", x.name());
}

fn main() {
  use(Box::new(A{});
}
```

There will be many cases and methods so I would like to avoid using massive match switching everywhere by use of virtual methods.

Am I even on the right track or is there a better alternative approach to this problem (not just dyn but the whole use of structs and dynamic traits)?

### Update regarding creating global boxes

Update: as noted in answers, boxes are not allocated in memory but rather are fat pointers (made of 2 pointers/usize values) that can be passed in registers so the paragraph below does not make sense.

I'm trying to avoid creating new box on every call to `use`.
I'm assuming even something like `use(&A{})` will allocate new box on stack.
Even if cheap it seems wasteful to recreate something that only needs to exist once.

I tried using lazy_static! but then type of value seemed unboxed:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref WIN: Box<dyn Named + Send + Sync> = Box::new(platform::Win{});
}

fn main() {
  foo(WIN); // does not compile - has type WIN but expected Box<dyn WIN>
  foo(&WIN); // compiles but I'm not sure if avoid creating box per each call?
}
```

### Update 2

Clarified that singletons are immutable and stateless and explained the meaning of Scala snippet.

Comment: *"it's not possible to impl on enum values in Rust"* – this statement is false, unless you meant enum variants, not values.

Comment: You don't need to create a new Box on every call, you can dispatch on a reference: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=acb181b0519210bf9ef7a134e57aabe8

Comment: @user4815162342 Isn't that allocating new `A{}` on a stack?

Comment: @MarcinWisnicki Not sure what you mean by "allocating". An `A` value has to exist if you need to call its method, right? On-stack "allocation" is as cheap as it gets, like any other local variable. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what your goal is - I thought the issue was the `Box`, but now it seems that you want to avoid creating any kind of `A` altogether. Perhaps you can create a `const A_SINGLETON: A = A {}` at top-level, and use that? Please edit the question to clarify what kind of code you'd **like** to write (in Rust rather than Scala).

Comment: Did you follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27826181) on how to create a singleton?

Comment: @E_net4 That answer seems like an overkill for the OP's case, as it's specifically about creating a **mutable** singleton. If the trait method signatures are to be believed, the OP doesn't need mutation, so no `Mutex` is necessary.

Comment: @user4815162342 but `&dyn Kind` will create new box on each call won't it? It's cheap but why create something that only needs to exist once? Also would like to know if maybe the whole approach is wrong/there is something better. BTW I can't tell you what kind of valid Rust code I would like as that would require knowing the answer. Just treat the Scala part as pseudocode example.

Comment: @E_net4 I tried using lazy static but failed, I'll update question with some details about that

Comment: `&dyn Kind` doesn't "create new box" or anything else, it receives a fat pointer. The fat pointer can point to something on the heap (which indeed requires allocating it first), or on the stack, in which case it entails no dynamic allocation. I can't treat Scala as pseudocode because I don't know enough Scala - in particular, I don't know how `use(A)` works nor whether that's considered to "allocate" an `A`. I suspect `use_kind(&A {})` is as fast as it gets, and probably as efficient as the Scala example, but I can't prove it without knowing Scala.

Comment: The more idiomatic answer would be, assuming the singletons are stateless, to see if you can replace the dynamic dispatch with static generic dispatch. Is this applicable to you design, or are the objects expected to be stateful?

Comment: Alternatively, consider if it would make sense to invert your code, so rather than separate blocks handling each polymorphic case, having a enum match for each behavior. If you want to you can then dispatch that to a static function.

Comment: @user1937198 just clarified that singletons are stateless and immutable. I'm trying to avoid manually writing dispatchers for number_of_variants * number_of_methods

Comment: @user4815162342 clarified that in Scala example only 2 objects are ever allocated and then `use(A)` gets pointer, i.e. 64 bit value known at compile time. Is fat pointer a struct with 2 pointers - for vtable and value on the stack?

Comment: BTW please post answers as answers since I can't accept comments

Comment: It was already explained to you that `foo(&WIN)` doesn't "create a box". You don't even need a `Box` in the lazy-static either. Not sure what more info you're missing. "Allocate Box on the stack" doesn't make sense either - you might be using the term "box" in a very non-standard way.

Comment: A fat pointer is a pair of two pointer-sized values, either two pointers or a pointer and a usize.

Comment: Apologies for the wrong use of the word allocate in context of Rust. It makes more sense in Java where boxes are indeed heap or stack allocated objects. In this case I simply wanted to know if `foo(&WIN)` is more expensive than standard C-style pass by reference (i.e. more than 1 register). Thanks to explanation from @cafce25 about unit struct constant promotion I now have better idea how this works.

Comment: If the singletons are truly stateless, maybe you don't need them at all. Devs coming from a Java background where generics are "erased" tend to forget that Rust supports generics on types rather than just values. Perhaps this is what you want: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=83ef346fa0ab3ba27b4876c7b17b5f6c (Edit: I now see that this exact code was already proposed by cafce25's answer!)

Comment: Parameters won't be know at compile time unfortunately which is what lead me to dyn.

Comment: Perhaps I should use enum_dispatch macro?

Comment: Then `dyn` is exactly the right approach, and (if done right) involves no heap allocations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither of your methods actually uses the receiver, so you can just ditch it and make them associated methods instead, this way the functions use no memory at all for the argument, but you need to know the type of `T` at compile time:

```rust
trait Kind {
    fn name() -> String;
}

struct A;
struct B;

impl Kind for A {
    fn name() -> String {
        String::from("A")
    }
}

impl Kind for B {
    fn name() -> String {
        String::from("B")
    }
}

fn use_static<T: Kind>() {
    println!("Kind is {}", T::name());
}

fn main() {
    use_static::<A>();
}
```

Of course if you actually need the dynamic dispatch, the [code suggested by user4815162342](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=acb181b0519210bf9ef7a134e57aabe8):

> ```
> fn use_kind(x: &dyn Kind) {
>     println!("Kind is {}", x.name());
> }
>
> fn main() {
>     use_kind(&A{});
> }
> ```

works just fine, it doesn't need to "allocate new box on stack" either, for one when we talk about boxes in Rust we almost exclusively talk about [`Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html) which is a primitive to put things on the *heap*, and it's not "allocating" anything on the stack either because `&A` with a unit struct (or other literal) is eligible for [constant promotion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html?highlight=promotion#constant-promotion) meaning it would be part of the binary, not a new memory slot on the stack (see also [Why can I return a reference to a local literal but not a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50345139/442760)).

Since it's a unit struct, the compiler does not need any space in the binary to store the struct `A` or `B` (or `()` for that matter), as can be seen when inspecting the addresses, they're all the same:

```rust
let x = 0;
println!("{:p}\n{:p}\n{:p}\n{:p}", &A, &B, &(), &x);
```

prints something like:

```
0x55d4f2d01010
0x55d4f2d01010
0x55d4f2d01010
0x7fff5f520c9c
```

illustrating all 3 unit structs are stored at the same address, which is noticably different from the memory slot on the stack reserved for `x`. With this dynamic dispatch the compiler passes 2 machine words (usually 2×8 bytes) to the function.

A third option is to use an enum instead of traits:

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
#[repr(u8)]
enum Kind {
    A,
    B,
}
impl Kind {
    fn name(self) -> String {
        match self {
            Self::A => String::from("A"),
            Self::B => String::from("B"),
        }
    }
}

fn use_enum(x: Kind) {
    println!("Kind is {}", x.name());
}

fn main() {
    use_enum(Kind::A);
}
```

It uses fewer bytes than dynamic dispatch (only a single byte for up to 256) but still works with dynamic arguments. Of course you can't as easily define the different behavior in different methods. That this miniscule difference in passed bytes actually makes a difference is questionable, on a 64bit system the single byte argument will usually just be passed in a 64bit register anyways. You should definitely benchmark and test it if you notice any bottleneck.

Comment: The type won't be known at compile time

Comment: Then you want to use the solution by user4815162342, I've added a bit about that as well. `&A` is eligible for constant promotion.

Comment: Thanks for explaining constant promotion of unit structs.

Comment: Interesting bit about dyn being able to use just one register. I could only find [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html?highlight=dyn#pointers-and-references-layout) that says dyn pointer is currently always 2*usize. Do you have any link about single register usage? How does it work, some form of pointer compression or eliding value for unit structs?

Comment: Where did you read that from? 2×8 bytes does not really fit in a regular 64bit register. The addresses of all unit s are the same is my point. It still has to pass the address + vtable to `use_kind` i.e. `sizeof::<&dyn Kind>()` is 16, not 8.

Comment: you wrote it at the end of your answer `on a 64bit system the argument will usually just be passed in a 64bit register anyways.` - I thought this referred to `dyn` as an explanation why static dispatch wouldn't make much difference.

Comment: Well all three versions are very likely either of 0, 1 or 2 registers passed, I doubt you'll notice a difference in any but the most extreme hot loops if even at all. But yea that statement only applies to the `enum` version.